# Calculating velocity

Tags: actionscript-3, math, physics

I want to calculate the start x and y speed of an object and it's velocity to make a curve before reaching the destination point. I tried to calculate it but it never reached the exact same x & y positions.

[image: Demostration]

Comment: Wait... what? Is there acceleration involved here? Like maybe gravity? And you know that *velocity* includes {x and y speed}, right?

Comment: Is the path of the object being curved due to gravity? If so, is gravity in your simulation calculated by "everything accelerates downward a constant amount", or "gravitational force for an object is based on its attraction towards other masses in the simulation"?

Comment: And what other restrictions are there? Is there a speed limit? A fixed time duration? Is there a desired amount of curve (and if so, how is it defined)?

Comment: +1 @Beta. If you are free to vary both the initial speed and angle of the object, then there are many possible solutions. Ex. a tall lazy arc vs. a straight shot towards the destination at light speed.

Comment: There is a fixed time duration, so I know how fast should it take.

Comment: If only gravity is involved in `y` direction, then the horizontal speed is constant due to momentum conservation. Divide the `x` distance by the time and you get the horizontal component of the initial speed. For the `y` velocity you have to solve a simple _linear_ equation. Then with a discrete finite-precision integration techniques (the only kind possible on digital computers), you will _not_ reach exactly the final coordinates in the general case, but rather an acceptable vicinity.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't specified, I'll assume that the acceleration is gravity acting in the **-y** direction.

You know the start and end points (**P** and **S**), and the time of flight (T), so this breaks down into motion problems:

In **x**, there is no acceleration, so the formula describing the motion is

x = v<sub>x</sub> t
v<sub>x</sub> = x/t
v<sub>x</sub> = (x<sub>S</sub>-x<sub>P</sub>)/T

In **y** there is constant downward acceleration (take g>0):

y = v<sub>i</sub> t - g t<sup>2</sup>/2
v<sub>i</sub> = y/T + g T/2
v<sub>y</sub> = (y<sub>S</sub>-y<sub>P</sub>)/T + g T/2

Comment: http://megaswf.com/s/2527424
It caused this.

Comment: Looks like a problem with gravity. Does your force of gravity act in the `-y` direction? ex. A point at (0,100) will fall down towards (0,0).

Comment: Well, the gravity is a constant but I think it shouldn't play in these calculation because it messes up the whole thing, if I put the too object close together, then it just flies away. And yes, I did.

Comment: @Zhafur, could you give us the *numbers*? The coordinates of P and S, your value for g, the v you caclulated, and maybe the coordinates of 2 or 3 of the points you plot?

Comment: The positions are dynamic, but let's assume that P(100;200) and S(400;300), g=0.7 and the velocity should depend on the distance, but it shouldn't take longer than T=20

Comment: So assume T=20. *What initial velocity did you calculate?*